# mounting/converting v2i image in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, images

Is it possible to mount a `v2i` image in linux?
Is there any `mount.v2i` program?
Or is there any convertion tool to convert `v2i` image to something else like `iso` ?
How can i Mount/Convert a `v2i` image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [OpenTheFile](http://www.openthefile.net/extension/v2i/7749) :

> V2I is a disk image backed up from a current volume using Norton Ghost. It contains a base backup of everything on the hard disk, and may be mounted as a new volume or restored to another disk **using Norton Ghost**.

Because of the last sentence, I would be tempted to say that this format can only be handled by Norton Ghost. Unfortunately <sup>*(or... fortunately?)*</sup> this piece of software is not available for Linux.

However, I came across [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) while Googling, the website of which states:

> Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program similar to True Image® or Norton Ghost®.

Because of these design similarities, Clonezilla might be able to manipulate a v2i file. It is available for Linux (Ubuntu and Debian seem to have it in their repositories).

Another solution would be to use a Windows virtual machine, on which you could mount the v2i image using Norton Ghost, and rebuild an ISO afterwards. You could also mount the v2i image under a shared mount point (*[Shared Folder](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)*) to allow Linux to access the image once it's mounted by Norton on the VM (*though I never tried such a thing...*).

You might also find [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/97234/norton-ghost-usage-linux-iso-server-mbr) interesting. Quoting [Molly7244's answer](https://superuser.com/a/97301/238103) to "*Does it mean that images can only be created from within a running Windows?*":

> No, Ghost.exe works in a DOS environment, however, for better controller controller support I recommend Ghost32.exe from within a Windows environment (e.g. BartPE)

In the same answer, you'll read that Symantec added support for ext2 and ext3 in 1999. Since most of us use ext4 now, I'd be tempted to say that their Linux support remains quite laughable. The SuperUser answer dates back to 2010, 2 years after ext4's stable introduction.

Comment: Clonezilla Limitations:
Due to the image format limitation, the image can not be explored or mounted. You can _NOT_ recovery single file from the image. However, you still have workaround to make it, read [this](http://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/43_read_ntfsimg_content.faq#43_read_ntfsimg_content.faq).